# How to connect a frontend application on a different port with a backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I put my frontend application in the public folder for a node.js application and am getting the form-data using the following request:

```
try {
  await axios.post("/api/v1/contact-form", {
    name,
    email,
    msg,
  }); 
}
```

My backend is in port 5000 and it's handling the request by:

```
app.use("/api/v1/contact-form", submitFormRouter);
```

It works perfect. I'm getting the data when I have my frontend application is in the node.js public folder.

My question is if my frontend is running on a different local port such as, if I use "Five server" to run the frontend application, how do I replace the following path for post:

Frontend:

```
try {
  await axios.post("/api/v1/contact-form", {
    name,
    email,
    msg,
  });
}
```

Backend:

```
app.use("/api/v1/contact-form", submitFormRouter)
```

I've also tried the code using React in which case the frontend is running in `http://localhost:3000/` and node.js server running in `5000`, the code still works and I'm getting the form data. But, how do I make it work for a frontend application sitting in a different port(without react)?

Additionally, I hope you're kind enough to answer the following question- What would be the path once I have the frontend let's say on Netlify whereas the backend is on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the path once I have the frontend let's say on Netlify whereas the backend is on Heroku?

Let's assume your Back on Heroku has this url `https://app.herokuapp.com/` and the Front on Netlify this one `https://app.netlify.com/`. All you have to do is to give your Front your Back's url, like so:

```
try {
  await axios.post("https://app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/contact-form", {
    name,
    email,
    msg,
  });
}
```

> My question is if my frontend is running on a different local port such as, if I use "Five server" to run the frontend application, how do I...

At this point you have two choices, the simplest one is to use a complete url like above. Let's assume your Front is on port `3000` and the Back on  `8080`. All you have to do again is:

```
try {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/contact-form", {
    name,
    email,
    msg,
  });
}
```

The second one is to use a `proxy`, and this really depends on your projects' structure and need.